# Quantity of force between two magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields, order-of-magnitude

I have compiled data detailing a magnetic field. If I assume a duplicate magnet is set up  across from it, how can I calculate the repulsive force between them?

Comment: We need additional information about the magnetic field $\textbf{B}$, the distance between the magnets, and the geometry of the magnet if you want a concise answer. Magnetic forces aren't trivial. 

Also, why was this voted down? It's an interesting question.

Comment: @Tetradic It was originally pretty unclear